# see/cf. followed by e.g. / for example

Tags: writing, writing-style, latin

Consider the following sentences:

- `foo` is `bar` (see, for example, `baz`).
- `foo` is `bar` (see, e.g., `baz`).
- `foo` is `bar` (cf. for example `baz`).
- `foo` is `bar` (cf. e.g., `baz`).

Which of these are valid to use, and which is better? Or - does it depend on what we actually instead of `foo`, `bar` and `baz`?

Comment: “cf.” means “compare”, not “see”. See, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.). And as for your question, cf., e.g., [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cf-e-g.1279636/).

Comment: @DanRomik: In that case, I've seen it misused. But +1 on your comment.

Comment: I've also seen it misused, but its proper use is well-defined (see, e.g. [cf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.)).

Answer (score 1):

The recent trend in non-legal English formal writing is to just use the English equivalent of the Latin abbreviation, so *compare* rather than *cf.* and *for example* rather than *e.g.* This also obviates the confusion about what *cf.* means and the distinction between *e.g.* and *i.e.*

On the other hand, using Latin abbreviations like *et al.* and *ibid.* for citations makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The term means compare.  So you would normally just see "c.f. X" where X is what you want compared.  Like:

Foo is bar (c.f. SNAFU).

P.s. You may have instances where you want to emphasize that there are many comparisons and thus use the e.g., but I would typically omit it and just give specific comparison(s).  Tighter writing.

Comment: "Cf." abbreviates a single Latin word (some form of _conferre_), so it only gets one period.